# send post request using wordpress api in node js

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm trying to send a post request using [wpapi](https://github.com/WP-API/node-wpapi) library.

Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246398/how-to-create-a-new-wordpress-post-using-the-wpapi-for-node-js)
I created an application password but still doesn't work.
can anybody help me here?

my code:

```
const WPAPI = require("wpapi");

 try {
  var ourPostData = {
    title: "dummy title",
    content: "dummy content",
    status: "draft",
  };


    var wp = new WPAPI({
      endpoint: "http://example.com/wp-json",
      username: "my username",
      password: "xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx",
    });

   await wp.posts()
      .create(JSON.stringify(ourPostData))
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.id); // This is undefined
      
      });

  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err", err); // No error
  }
```

Comment: For the better understanding of the question please do post the Error message, with the version of the package used. Please let me know if the solution works for you or not!

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't mentioned the version of **Wpapi** , i am writing the solution for the latest *[version 1.2.2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wpapi)*

```
    import WPAPI from "wpapi";
    const wp = new WPAPI({ endpoint: "https://example.com/wp-json" });
    
    const token = { username: "admin", password: "XXX XXX XXX XXX" };
    const post_data = {
      title: "My First API Post",
      content: "Hello world! This is my first post using the WordPress REST API.",
    };
    
    wp.posts()
      .auth(token)
      .create(post_data)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Article posted:", response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

**Side Note:** when you create the new application password, it is not the username, the username is which you use to login as a default wordPress user. The Name which you create while creating the Application is for the admin to understand and keep the track.